# What is a good http benchmark program for Mac OS X?

Tags: software-recommendation, http, benchmark

What is a good http benchmark program for Mac OS X?

I have Apache's 'ab' installed, but it's buggy and there doesn't seem to be a Mac OS X package for Apache as an upgrade. I don't like compiling and installing from source because it's unmanaged. I use Homebrew as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could try Seige: http://freecode.com/projects/siege

Comment: This works well and is also in the Homebrew system